# $P(B|G) = P(B, G) /P(G) = P(B)/P(G)$

Tags: probability

Reading the following statement

> Then the event “no girls” has probability $1/4$, the event “one girl,
>   one boy” has probability $1/2$, and the event “two girls” has
>   probability $1/4$. Now we can ask what is the probability of the event
>   “both children are girls” ($B$) conditional on the event “the older
>   child is a girl” ($G$)? Using the definition of conditional probability:

$P(B|G) = \dfrac{P(B, G)}{P(G)} = \dfrac{P(B)}{P(G)} = 1/2$

> since the event $B$ and $G$ (“both children are girls and the older child is a girl”) is just the event $B$. (Once you know that both children are girls, it’s necessarily true that the older child is a girl.)

I am very confused with "$\dfrac{P(B, G)}{P(G)} = \dfrac{P(B)}{P(G)}$"

How could deduce $P(B, G) = P(B)$?

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding the logic behind the second piece of text you quote?

Comment: thank you, it's very interesting that I was clicked immediately after writing down the question. @Arthur